# MSTests are getting automatically ignored?

Tags: c#, testing, mstest

I'm debugging an mstest using Resharper, I put a breakpoint and step into into it and everything works fine. That's for a few times (say 50).

After that, when I hit debug, it seems like it's doing something and eventually the test goes into "Ignored" in my test results. I've put a breakpoint at the beggining {, but it seems like it doesn't even enter the test.

That goes away if I restart my VS2012, and returns after a couple of runs, or goes away completely if I restart my PC. So I suspect something with memory is the issue. Anyone had similar issues?

Comment: I have had this happen to me in the past too.  There is no real 'fix' I was ever able to put my finger on so, I just moved to a different testing framework.  If this is an option for you, I would strongly recommend that you look into it.  MSTest is not a good test framework, unfortunately.

Comment: Well...unfortunately it is not an option, however I'll update this thread when I cleanup my dev pc which I haven't for 1,5 now...

Comment: Could you possibly post the code for the test that is having the issue as well?  There could be something in it that is adding to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, though it's not one test, it's any test that will behave likewise.